# How to align two FloatingActionButtons together in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, floating-action-button

So I'm trying to align two `FloatingActionButton`s in a `LinearLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`.
Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/DeleteBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But I want them to behave like any other element like a `TextView` when you put them inside a `LinearLayout`. 
I mean I want them each to take half of the `LinearLayout`'s width.
But they would stick at the `LinearLayout`'s start and they won't move no matter what I try.

I tried using `android:layout_width="1"` on each of them but no luck, they won't move at all they are just stuck together at the start of the `LinearLayout`.

Here's how it looks:

[image: It looks like this]

I would be so glad if there's any suggestions! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want one floating button on left side and another one right side correct ?

Comment: @PraveenSP yeah, taking width evenly

Comment: set the `layout_weight` 1 in both of them and gravity as `Start`. Try it

Comment: @LalitFauzdar nah, didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve it is like this ...

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_forever_black_24dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It will look something like this ....[image]

You can play with layout_gravity to align those as you want...

Comment: Not a problem happy coding... :)

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use Below this XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
       >
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/DeleteBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works, thank you. but I wanted both buttons to be at center but this aligns them to the right. Anyway I managed to make it work by setting both internal `LinearLayouts`' `gravity` to `center`.

Answer (score 1):

With some simple math you could have the perfect alignment with this code, just copy paste:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/DeleteBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Centered exactly without big gap at the center:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/DeleteBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, changing the layout_weight won't work for this situation for some reason

Answer (score 0):

in LinearLayout you can set layout_weight=1 to share parent :

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: I wish this worked but as I mentioned in my question changing the weight doesn't work.

Comment: must be in linearlayout? it can implement in constraintLayout easily

Comment: I think LinearLayout is the best layout in my case, but thanks i will check if that works as well.